# AndroidManifest.xml and style

Tags: android

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MyHomePage" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Light" android:label="New Tasks"/>
```

I have that Activity in my AndroidManifest.xml file. How do I set style on that android:label. I would like to set textsize and textcolor.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">  
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTextSize</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">14pt</item>
</style>
```

OR

```
<style name="ActionBarTextSize" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">14pt</item>
     </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about creating a custom window title style? If so, check this out: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/